# ODBC Connection from Domain Win 7 Client to Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, odbc

Trying to setup an ODBC connection for UPS to access our SQL server, from our shipping client computer.

I have scoured as much as I can an ran across:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\account "c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe"
```

Now, using this method, on my current client computer, I was able to setup an odbc connection successfully using SQL Native Client 11 (5058). I am using Win 10. Our shipping computer, with multiple manifest systems on it, is still using Win 7, but otherwise is setup the same on the domain.

Using the same process as above, the connection ultimately times out, and states that the server is not online/not available/not allowing remote connections.

Is there a step I'm missing? Both clients have same rules for firewall, both are using the same user/password in the runas cmd. The only difference between the two clients is Win 10 vs. Win 7, and the current logged in user is different (but that shouldn't matter with the runas cmd?)

Thanks!

Comment: So I think I have discovered the root of the problem, but have not yet found a solution. The runas command worked on the Win 10 computer, because the OS is 64-bit and it was running the 64-bit ODBC panel from the system32 folder, the Win 7 PC is 32 bit OS, and was running the 32-bit ODBC panel from the system32. Both are trying to connect to a Server 2012 SQL 64-bit. So, why would a 32-bit connection not work, and what additional setup do I need to do on the client (or server) to allow it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several days/hours of trying various solutions and suggestions from all over the interwebs, I came across this solution/tips.

In SQL Server Configuration, checking the network configuration protocols/clients/aliases. In my case, there was an aliases established for 32-bit, and not 64-bit. I disabled the 32-bit one.

I then found suggestions to us the ip (which I had tried in the past, with no success), but this time, after ensuring all the tcp/ip protocols were enabled and the 32-bit aliases was disabled, I was able to connect the 32-bit to the 64-bit SQL server, using the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx address of the server.

Test came back successful!